# programmatically get portlet assignment for portlet displayed by item display dynamic view

Tags: ajax, plone, portlet

In an ajax callback browser view to update an on the filesystem developed custom portlet I have the following code to retrieve the associated portlet assignment of the portlet generating the ajax request:

```
def getPortletById(self, content, portletManager, key, name):
    manager = getUtility(IPortletManager, name=portletManager, context=content)
    retriever = getMultiAdapter((content, manager,), IPortletRetriever)

    print "getPortletById:  ",content, portletManager, key, name
    print "iterating portlet assignements:"
    for assignment in retriever.getPortlets():
        print assignment["key"], assignment["name"]
        if assignment["key"] == key and assignment["name"] == name:
            return assignment["assignment"]
    return None

def getPortletManager(self, column):
    manager = getUtility(IPortletManager, name=column)
    return manager

def render(self):
    print "refreshment of moonphase portlet"
    content = self.context.aq_inner

    print self.context
    name = self.request.form.get("portletName")
    managername = self.request.form.get("portletManager")
    key = self.request.form.get("portletKey")

    print name, managername, key
    portlet = self.getPortletById(content, managername, key, name)
    manager = self.getPortletManager(managername)
    managerRenderer = manager(content, self.request, self)
    renderer = managerRenderer._dataToPortlet(portlet.data)
    renderer.update()
    return renderer.render()
```

This works well as long the portlets generating the requests are directly assigned to content or its parent folders and displayed. But when I set the default view of a folder
to a content item with a portlet assigned to it, the iteration does not find the portlet rendered on the page as part of the default folder view.

```
<PloneSite at naturfreundeskreis>
moonphase-portlet plone.rightcolumn /naturfreundeskreis/naturfreundeskreis
getPortletById:   <PloneSite at naturfreundeskreis> plone.rightcolumns /naturfreundeskreis/naturfreundeskreis moonphase-portlet
iterating portlet assignements
/naturfreundeskreis calendar
2013-03-19 13:48:31 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1363715311.150.739587723624 http://midgard.user.openhosting.com:8280/naturfreundeskreis/@@refreshMoonphase
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module kuehnel.portlets.moonphase.moonphaseview, line 21, in __call__
Module kuehnel.portlets.moonphase.moonphaseview, line 59, in render
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

The initial portlet rendering process did somehow find the portlet, as it is displayed and generates the request. But I cannot. What did I wrong?

Is it good practice to use a browser view to deliver ajax requested content pieces?

I'll update the github repo of the whole portlet at https://github.com/tdkuehnel/kuehnel.portlets.moonphase at end of day to reflect the current development status.

Plone 4.2.4 buildout on Centos

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've got the problem.

The portlet rendering machinery gets kicked in twice *it looks like* to render

- a: the portlets of the current folder
- b: the portlets of the document set as default_page on that folder

Somehow. I don't know exactly how the machinery avoids to render the *parent* portlets again in this process, but the piece of information itself is enough to adapt my ajax callback routine in the browser view as follows:

```
def render(self):
    ...
    portlet = self.getPortletById(content, managername, key, name)
    if not portlet:
        # let's try to find it assigned on the default_page view
        defaultpage = getattr(content,getattr(content,"default_page",None),None)
        if defaultpage:
            portlet = self.getPortletById(defaultpage, managername, key, name)
            content = defaultpage
        else:
            logger.warn('cannot find an assignment for a portlet of type %s in ajax update request' % name)
            return None
    ...
```

and it works now. But i wonder if its really needed for a developer to deal with such special cases in their code with all that adapter and interface stuff around that *should* take care of everything. 
How can I know of what PortletManagers and/or Retrievers someone develops to display my portlet in. I cannot take care of special cases *not even developed*, so I think I miss something in my find-the-way-to-my-portlet code. Hope it. Or the portlet machinery needs to be adapted. Someone please shed some light onto this.